# Explain "this.type" as a return type of various API methods

Tags: scala

I am looking though the source code of the `Promise[T]` trait from the `scala.concurrent` package.
So here is the method declaration where I need your help in one place:

```
trait Promise[T] {
 ....
 def complete(result: Try[T]): this.type =
 if (tryComplete(result)) this else throw new IllegalStateException("Promise already completed.")
 ....
}
```

I do not really understand how to interpret the `this.type` as a `complete` method return type. Why not simple the return type could be `Promise[T]` ?

Sorry if my question will seem too simple for someone, I am just learning this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.type` is necessary in a path dependent context:

```
scala> class A { class B; def f(b: B): A = this }
defined class A

scala> val a1 = new A; val b1 = new a1.B; val a2 = new A
a1: A = A@721f1edb
b1: a1.B = A$B@5922f665
a2: A = A@65e8e9b

scala> a1.f(b1)
res6: A = A@721f1edb

scala> a2.f(b1)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a1.B
 required: a2.B
              a2.f(b1)
                   ^
```

Path dependent means that the compiler knows that types belong together. In the above example one can see that `new a1.B` produces a value of type `a1.B` and not only `B`. However, this does not work:

```
scala> a1.f(b1).f(b1)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a1.B
 required: _2.B where val _2: A
              a1.f(b1).f(b1)
                         ^
```

The problem is that the return type of `f` is `A`, which has no information anymore about the path dependent relationship. Returning `this.type` instead tells the compiler that the return type fulfills this relationship:

```
scala> class A { class B; def f(b: B): this.type = this }
defined class A

scala> val a1 = new A; val b1 = new a1.B; val a2 = new A
a1: A = A@60c40d9c
b1: a1.B = A$B@6759ae65
a2: A = A@30c89de5

scala> a1.f(b1).f(b1)
res10: a1.type = A@60c40d9c
```

Comment: Could you highlight where in the [Promise.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/concurrent/Promise.scala#L1) are path dependent types? Is it in other places where the `Promise` is mixed in?

Comment: path dependent types are inherited to the subclasses, see Gabrieles answer (and the implementation of [Promise](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1d8e8ffa0f9e3334d4387b6dc074f924b41410ce/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L21)) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reason is supporting inheritance.

Consider this simple example

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def foo: Foo[A] = this
}

trait Bar[A] extends Foo[A]
```

Now let's try it out

```
scala> (new Foo[Int]{}).foo
res0: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@7f0aa670

scala> (new Bar[Int]{}).foo
res1: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@4ee2dd22
```

As you can see, the method `foo` returns a `Foo[Int]` in both cases, and that's because you returned the "hardcoded" type `Foo[T]` in the method definition.

If you instead do

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def foo: this.type = this
}

trait Bar[A] extends Foo[A]
```

then the returned type depends on the instance you're invoking `foo` on:

```
scala> (new Foo[Int]{}).foo
res2: Foo[Int] = $anon$1@1391e025

scala> (new Bar[Int]{}).foo
res3: Bar[Int] = $anon$1@4142991e
```

Comment: that's a valid point but I think that classical inheritance idea is to operate with super-type references when dealing with a sub-type values. I mean that there is nothing wrong and probably in most cases it is good to treat an instance of a `Bar[Int]` as a `Foo[Int]`. So I don't think your explanation is really the reason why they used this way of return type expression.

Comment: well, yes and no. The reason why trait exists, is also for providing default implementations of methods. When you extend a trait you want some methods implemented for free, without losing type precision. Think of a trait A with two methods, one abstract and one concrete, which both returning `this.type`. When you implement the abstract method in a class `B`, you want both to return an instance of the same type, as opposed to one returning `A` and one `B`. Ultimately this is a special case of path dependent types, after all.

Comment: Yes, I see. I agree with you.